# How to listen to failed test with protractor and mocha

Tags: protractor, mocha.js, allure

I am using the allure reporter and want to attach screenshots to it when a test fails. For this I need to listen to the `runner.on('fail', function(){});` event and attach the screenshot to allure inside this event.

But I have no idea how to pass the runner from the onPrepare function in the protractor conf file.
Any ideas how to solve this?